# Find subgraph in neo4j with limits on number of connections

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I need to perform a query on a large <1million node graph where for a given connection I want to perform a breadth first search on the nodes it connects too, provided the BFS won't return too many nodes, else I don't want any returned. (I'll assume these are famous nodes that are known and connect many different subgraphs too each other. I have labelled in green and red the nods and links I need back vs those that I don't. I'm guessing this would probably be an APOC, but I'm a little lost.[image: Get all]

[image: Partial subgraph]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the following to identify the relationship of interest:

```
MATCH (a:Foo)-[b:BAR]->(c:Foo)
WHERE b.id = 123
```

here is one way you can avoid returning unwanted nodes (those on the left or right side of your diagram, if there are 5 or more of them):

```
MATCH (a:Foo)-[b:BAR]->(c:Foo)
WHERE b.id = 123
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)--(x)
WITH a, b, c, [z IN COLLECT(x) WHERE z <> c] AS xs
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)--(y)
WITH a, b, c, xs, [z IN COLLECT(y) WHERE z <> a] AS ys
RETURN a, b, c,
  CASE WHEN SIZE(xs) < 5 THEN xs ELSE [] END AS xs,
  CASE WHEN SIZE(ys) < 5 THEN ys ELSE [] END AS ys
```